# Notification is not coming in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone, app-store

Hi,

I have upgraded Windows Phone 8 app to silverlight 8.1 app. Then I have uploaded this silverlight app to devcenter and it is successfully listed in store and downloaded also. Now problem is Notification is not working in Windows Phone SilverLight 8.1 app
 but it is working in Windows Phone 8 App. I have not change in code as well as any Submission process in Devcenter. In
**App info** at Devcenter I have just add **App alias and Category** nothing else. And in **Upload and describe your package** I have Fill all require Field.

i have follow these below links

[For upgrade Wp8 to SilverLight 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UpgradeyourWindowsPhone8apptoSilverlight81) and [For
 toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx)

Thank You,

---

shah

Comment: Is it possible that the app got a new secret?

Comment: how can it possible?

Comment: I don't know. I would check that in the dev center und the app's details just to be sure.

Comment: No, I have not upgrade App to store there are two different app is listed 1 is windows phone 8 app and another one is Windows phone silverlight 8.1 app